# Efficient way to model to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm a Cassandra newbie and I'm trying to model this json to cassandra tables

- the module has N criteria
- the criteria has N procedure
- the procedure has N activities
- the activity has N tasks

-

```
{
    "module": [{
        "id": "xxxxxx",
        "type": "module",
        "name": "xxxxxxx",
        "criteria": [{
            "id": "xxxxxx",
            "type": "crieria",
            "name": "xxxxxxx",
            "procedure": [{
                "id": "xxxxxx",
                "type": "procedure",
                "name": "xxxxxxx",
                "activity": [{
                    "id": "xxxxxx",
                    "type": "activity",
                    "name": "xxxxxxx",
                    "task": [{
                        "id": "xxxxxx",
                        "type": "activity",
                        "name": "xxxxxxx",
                        "user_assigned": "xxxxxx"
                        "date": "xxxxxxx"
                    },
                        ....     
                    ]
                },
                    ....
                ]
            },
                ....
            ]
        },
            ....
        ]
    },
    ....
    ]
}
```

I was trying with UDT but **Non-frozen UDTs are not allowed inside collections: map** and I want to let the user update specific parts.

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS task (
    id text,
    enumerate text,
    name text,
    user_assigned text,
    description text
);


CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS activity (
    id text,
    enumerate text,
    name text,
    description text,
    task map<int, frozen<task>>
);


CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS procedure (
        id text,
        enumerate text,
        name text,
        description text,
        activity map<int, frozen<activity>>
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS criteria (
    id text,
    enumerate text,
    name text,
    description text,
    procedure map<int, frozen<procedure>>
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS module (
    id text,
    enumerate text,
    name text,
    description text,
    criteria map<int, frozen<criteria>>
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS certification (
    id timeuuid,
    owner text,
    description text,
    name text,
    template map<int, frozen<module>>,
    images map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, owner)
);
```

I've [limitations if I use collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html)

The [recomendations](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-modeling-with/9781491979723/ch01.html) are to try query-first approach to start designing but I want to start showing all the data and go in by links to the tasks

what is the best way to model it?.

**UPDATE**

Queries I need

- Q1. Lookup modules by ID.
- Q2. Lookup for modules, criteria, procedure, activity in the same
  time
- Q3. Lookup tasks by user_assigned
- Q4. Lookup tasks by activity

Comment: List up all your query, In Cassandra table are designed according to your query

Comment: what are the access patterns for your data? how do you need to read and write it? perhaps the best approach is to store the json as a blob?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I update the question and it have the queries

Comment: @FuzzyAmi I need to know the modules and modules with all the information inside, and need just tasks